# Function for replacing part of a string using regex (python 3.7)

Tags: python

I need to define a function that given a string, finds the first appearance of the substring 'not' and 'bad'.
If the 'bad' follows the 'not', replace the whole " 'not'...'bad' " substring with 'good'.

So 'This dinner is not that bad!' yields: This dinner is good!

I tried to do something like that but it doesn't work:

```
g='this dinner is not that bad'

def not_bad(g):
    return (g.replace('not(.*)bad','good'))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str.replace()` does not recognize regular expressions.

To perform a substitution using a regular expression, use `re.sub()`

> The **re.sub()** function in the re module can be used to replace
>   substrings.
>
> The syntax for re.sub() is `re.sub(pattern,repl,string)`.
>
> That will replace the matches in string with repl.

```
import re

def not_bad(g):
    return re.sub(r'not.+bad','good',g)

g='this dinner is not that bad '
print (not_bad(g))
```

output:

```
this dinner is good
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, str.replace(str_pattern, str_replacement) replaces an exact string with another exact string. You need to use the re (regular expression) module to replace a regular expression pattern with a string.

```
import re

g = 'this dinner is not that bad'

def not_bad(g):
    return re.sub('not(.*)bad','good', g)

not_bad(g) => 'this dinner is good'
```